# Is there a time in Star Trek where "bypass the plasma/EPS" relays failed and caused damage to the ship?

Tags: star-trek

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpJ_6LCly4A) today by Cathode Ray Dude who made an analogy to real life battle shorts to the fictional plasma/EPS relays that are frequently "bypassed" in the Star Trek TV series as a way to force a system to respond to a command.

There are a lot of episodes across several different series, and I seem to recall some instances where the bypass worked, but then there was then a small explosion a few moments later, possibly indicating a surge (I may be misremembering this one).

My question is, was there ever an instance in any of the series where an attempt was made to bypass a relay, it failed, and there was some kind of explosion or subsequent damage from the attempt?

Comment: It doesn't have to be any specific kind of relay; plasma and EPS are just examples. Did they bypass some kind of relay? Did it fail? Was there damage or an explosion? That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: The only specific mention of bypassing a plasma relay listed on Memory Alpha (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Plasma_relay) is in a single Voyager episode, referring to a shuttle that's being renovated.